# Is it a bad design to have different footer position on main page and sub pages?

Tags: html, css, footer

There's this bug that I can't seem to fix where IE cuts off part of my text if I leave the footer in the same exact place as the main page. The following are examples of my main page footer position and the subpage footer position. I was wondering is it bad design to move the footer position this way? (the flow of the site fits better with the moving of the footer though)

Main page: http://www.sixfoldstudios.com/stars/index.html
Subpages: http://www.sixfoldstudios.com/stars/home.html

Thanks!

Comment: Voting to close for being off topic. This isn't programming related, it isn't even a technical question about HTML or CSS. Maybe Doctype would be a better fit?

Comment: Belongs on http://ui.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would keep the footer the same everywhere. The reason why you might have a problem is because your footer div is in the rightcontent div.

Just move it outside just before the closing div of your container and if text overlaps it set the css to clear:both;

Answer (score 1):

The footer doesn't look all that different except that it is smaller on the subpages. This is not a bad design decision.

As long as the footer looks the same overall and doesn't throws the text around it should be okay. People don't really look at the footer unless they need something from it so I'm sure most visitors won't even notice.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a designer, so I can't answer you from this scope. But as user, I can't say that looks bad, your footer doesn't include any great information for the end user, that will visit just the website, I doubt if most users even check it. Of course the things change if you had a sitemap. Also big sites use different position for footers, here an example of ebay.

Homepage: http://www.ebay.com/

Answers Center: http://pages.ebay.com/community/answercenter/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I have two sets of class for both me mainpage & subpages footer at times & it doesn't bother me much as long it does it work ^_^